# Sort the keys of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

dict:

```
d1 = {'b,a':12,'b,c,a':13}
```

Code:

```
x = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d1.items()))
print(x)
```

Not getting the expected output.

Expected Output:

```
d1 = {'a,b': 12, 'a,b,c':13}
```

Comment: `collections.OrderedDict( sorted((",".join(sorted(k.split(","))), v) for k, v in d1.items()))`, you need to sort the keys and the items if you want both ordered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't actually want to sort the keys, you want to re-arrange the non-comma substrings of your keys such that these substrings are ordered.

```
>>> d1 = {'b,a':12,'b,c,a':13}
>>> {','.join(sorted(key.split(','))):val for key, val in d1.items()}
{'a,b': 12, 'a,b,c': 13}
```

Answer (score -1):

d1.items(): returns a list of (key, value) tuples

sorted(d1.items()): simply sorts the above list

If you want to sort the items in your keys, then you need to run sort on your keys.